# ignoring parentheses and first occurance with re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am working on a re pattern that replaces items that matches with the dictionary. However, the code I wrote substitute every match. Is there any way to ignoring the paranthesis and first match? Below, you can find an example text.

**Input:**

```
s = " SHOO (/ˈshuː/ suhuu) is derivered from Shi Hoo oop our something. SHOO represents title. fu oop our ( FOO ) prefers the name TOP-SHOO.[3] SHOO is one of FOO.Tu REST (tREST) means empty. tREST differs with REST. Doot Ooop Our sour (DOOs) is also means bla. DOOs are friendly."
```

**Expected Output:**

```
" SHOO (/ˈshuː/ suhuu) is derivered from Shi Hoo oop our is something. Shi Hoo oop our represents title. fu oop our ( FOO ) prefers the name TOP-SHOO.[3] Shi Hoo oop our is one of fu oop our.Tu REST (tREST) means empty. tu REST differs with REST. Doot Ooop Our sour (DOOs) is also means bla. Doot Ooop Our sour are friendly."
```

```
import re

d = {
'tREST':'tu REST',
'FOO': 'fu oop our',
'SHOO': 'Shi Hoo oop our',
'DOOs': 'Doot Ooop Our sour',
'TOP-SHOO' : None
}

for k, v in d.items():
    if v is None:
        d[k] = k

pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r')\b')

result = pattern.sub(lambda x: d[x.group()], ' '.join(s.split()))
```

Comment: It is difficult to see how you want to change the text. That's in part because the example is so long and also because the string `s` (presumably the input) consists of several lines, each ending with a period, whereas the "expected output" is also a string with multiple lines but with different line endings (not at periods). I suggest you edit, making your example as short as possible without simplifying away the meaning. Show the input (with a variable attached `s = "...."`) and the expected result, and then introduce your code.

Comment: edited the original post based on your feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's one approach. The idea is to use the newer regex module with the ability to skip anything in parentheses (this is done via `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`) and to implement a tuple with a count rather than the values alone. Lastly, we use a replacement function that counts the substitutes:

```
import regex as re

# make a tuple out of it
d = {
    'tREST':    ('tu REST', 0),
    'FOO':      ('fu oop our', 0),
    'SHOO':     ('Shi Hoo oop our', 0),
    'DOOs':     ('Doot Ooop Our sour', 0),
    'TOP-SHOO': (None, 0)
}

# clear out Nones
for k, v in d.items():
    if v[0] is None:
        d[k] = (k, 0)

# pattern with r- and f-strings
pattern = re.compile(rf'''
    \([^()]+\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
    |
    \b{"|".join(d.keys())}\b
''', re.VERBOSE)

# here comes the magic
def replacer(match):
    key = match.group(0)
    try:
        value, cnt = d[key]
        result = value if cnt else key
        cnt += 1
        d[key] = (value, cnt)
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return result

output = pattern.sub(replacer, s)
print(output)
```

A bit unclear is, how you want to treat e.g. `bla bla bla (FOO). bla FOO bla bla.` - replace the second `FOO` as it is the second or leave it as we're ignoring anything between parentheses anyway?

---

### Possible optimizations

You could leave the initial dict as it is as we're looping over it anyway and can then make a tuple out of the values. This might be easier to maintain (adding new substitues, that is):

```
# a dict
d = {
    'tREST':    'tu REST',
    'FOO':      'fu oop our',
    'SHOO':     'Shi Hoo oop our',
    'DOOs':     'Doot Ooop Our sour',
    'TOP-SHOO':  None
}

# clear out Nones
for k, v in d.items():
    if v is None:
        d[k] = (k, 0)
    else:
        d[k] = (v, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. For your question, if the first FOO occured in paranthesis, the second FOO should be replaced. I also tried your example in a sentence like "The latter procedure is similar to FOO dTRU".  Both words occured before that sentence in paranthesis. What I found is it skips FOO but replaces dTRU. Is this problem can only solved by regex or re can handle with this situation too?